# Xserver not starting on Ryzen 3800x + RTX2070

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, xorg

I've been trying to solve this on my own, but I'm at my wit's end.

I've just upgraded from an Intel 7600 to a Ryzen 3800x, and now I'm having issues with Xserver which won't start.

It used to work fine on the upgraded computer, and still works fine on a laptop with an Intel CPU and NVidia GPU.

I've uploaded my `Xorg.0.log` and `xorg.conf` to this gist https://gist.github.com/p-avital/b958a466ca828a52486d6e7271648973

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` was apparently the issue, I just moved it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup` and xorg figured it all out by itself.